# Get text between quotes in WebBrowser or HttpWebRequest? VB.NET

Tags: api, quotes

I have an API, the API returns the input like this:

```
{"phrase":"decrypted","parsed":"encryptedcode","response":"done","code":6}
```

Everything around "decrypted" and "encryptedcode" stays the same.

I need to get the "decrypted" part only. No idea where to even begin.

I'm using WebBrowser, since I'm not any good at HttpWebRequest, so if you could answer as WebBrowser code instead of HttpWebRequest, I would appreciate it.

**Answer**

```
clean = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText.Replace("phrase", "").Replace(":", "").Replace("parsed", "").Replace(md5, "").Replace("code", "").Replace("The MD5 hash was cracked.", "").Replace("""", "").Replace("6", "").Replace("}", "").Replace("{", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("response", "")
```

so I could do

```
listbox.items.add(clean)
```

and it wouldn't look messy.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace `:` to `,`

Then you input looks like

```
{"phrase", "decrypted", "parsed", "encryptedcode", "response", "done", "code", 6}
```

then do as below

```
Dim str() As String = {"phrase", "decrypted", "parsed", "encryptedcode", "response", "done", "code", 6}
Dim decrypted As String = str(1)
```

you get `Decrypted` part

Comment: I already answered my question haha. I just needed the output to be just the decrypted part.